# Antonym of "highlight" (as in highlight of the movie)

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests, antonyms

What's the opposite of *highlight*?

I don't mean the verb *to highlight* or *to emphasize* something, so *downplay* isn't an option.

Instead I'm looking for the opposite of "the highlight of the movie, concert, show".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would most likely say ***low point***.

Comment: that would be the german antonym *Tief-punkt*. And *high point* seems not very common, that's why I asked, I couldn't find better words than *low point*

Comment: I don't think you need a "better" word than it, personally; it's quite common and means exactly what you're talking about. @Barrie's suggestion of *nadir* is a more eloquent word meaning the same thing, though.

Comment: @onomatomiak So can I use the "high and low points of a show" for a report or "highlights and low points". Sounds both a bit awkward to me, but I'm no native speaker

Comment: I think either would be fine - neither sounds particularly awkward to this native speaker. If you really want symmetry, though, *lowlight* is a word, if a newish one; you could say "highlights and lowlights" and everyone would understand you. You could also just say the show had its *highs and lows*.

Comment: *Low point* is what *NME* uses for [festival](http://www.nme.com/blog/index.php?blog=120&title=arctic_monkeys_at_t_in_the_park_2011_rev&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) [set](http://www.nme.com/blog/index.php?blog=120&title=beady_eye_at_isle_of_wight_festival_2011_2012&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) [reviews](http://www.nme.com/blog/index.php?blog=120&p=10574&more=1&c=1), and also used more often at the *Guardian* than *nadir*, in this context.

Answer (score 22):

*Nadir* is the opposite of *zenith*, but could conceivably be used, as in *The nadir comes when the leading actor tries to sing.*

Comment: +1 I think that's perfectly valid usage. The only caveat I'd add is that you can't really pluralize it (whereas there can be more than one highlight to a show).

Comment: +1 thanks fot this foreign word, I still hope there is a more common english term. @onomatomaniak good point, **plural should be possible**

Comment: @Hauser: *Nadir* has been part of the English language [since the 15th century](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nadir), so I think it's a bit much to call it a "foreign word". Would you say that of all words with Latin roots?

Comment: @FumbleFingers surely not, but we agree that it doesn't sound like a english word, very seldom morphemes it consists of, I never heard it, zenith is pretty common

Comment: @Hauser: Neither word sounds particularly "Anglo-Saxon" to me, if that's what you mean. But I actually suspect that metaphorical *zenith* (as opposed to the astronomical context) may even be *less* common than *nadir* (which is effectively always a simple literal term). Perhaps we just move in different linguistic circles!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "nadir" and "zenith" are of Arabic origin. In that sense, you could call them foreign words. They are used in exactly the same form in other languages too, no plural forms, just like in English.

Comment: I don't use "nadir" often, except when I'm making fun of Ralph's politics, but it is a perfectly good English word. I always thought of it as the opposite of "acme" when discussing the highs and lows of a trend. I didn't know it was an astronomical term that was the antonym of zenith until today. Google's Ngram viewer seems popular here: it shows "nadir" as only slightly less popular than "zenith" and more popular than "acme". (The latter is, for some reason, mostly used for the name of an example company these days, as in, "Suppose we had a company, let's call it Acme Widget Company ...")

Comment: @Jay: I'm suprised to learn that RN is still around.

Answer (score 19):

Why don't you use [lowlight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lowlight)?

Comment: makes less sense to me, imho you can only emphasize something by using e.g. a (spot)light, you cannot set it in the background this way. Highlight is a metaphor, building the anti-form doesn't work here often very well imo, that why you use downplay for the verb

Answer (score 2):

How about a *low [ebb](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=ebb&title=21st)*?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for nadir, but I have one problem with it: a highlight in the movie example can be other things (a theme, a broader message), too, whereas nadir is restricted to meaning a point in the story line, or a particular scene in the movie

Answer (score 1):

If you're going with "highlight" as a verb, I'd offer "diminish" as an antonym.

> His year was highlighted by his league leading batting average but diminished by his poor performance during the World Series.

Answer (score -4):

How about *downfall*? Could it fit in this context? "What was the highlight of the week? and the downfall?"

Comment: *Downfall* usually means something else entirely. 'The downfall of the wicked' is not just them having a bad day.

Answer (score -6):

opposite of highlight is low profile